# PDF not exporting to Excel

Tags: c#, report

I had my desktop system converted to the web, and now I am struggling as the developer died! My main issue at the moment is that the reports are pdf and the customer has been used to right clicking on them and exporting to Excel - why is this now not available?

Comment: Read through [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) will help you propose an efficient question.

Answer (score 0):

It exist. It is called OCR (Optical Character Recognition).

A little google will suggest you plenty of ready made tools. Leaving you with the question of redoing the format.